# React - Looking for different approach/idea to creating this React component

Tags: reactjs

I want to know what approach you would use in ReactJS to create 3 block's that have the same styling and same slider effect showing in photo below:

In my mind, I want to do a loop in ReactJs but my question by doing that if I created a back-end to let the user update the contents like texts and images.

[image]

**Note:** I don't need to know how to style it I just want to know different approaches to building this react component from front-end/back-end developers.

Comment: Post some code, to get more information on how are you approaching your issue, or create a codesandbox that could enable us to play and move some stuff in your code

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez I don't have any code just want ideas and not an issue. I just want some ideas to create this component. To, just started out

Answer (score 1):

There should be three Components here in my opinion.

The Carosuel Component, which has

- Recent Activities
- Weddings
- View More Button
- Mapping of all images in an Image Component described below

The Image component 
Grey background would be an image ofcourse

- With Title
- With Caption
- Button overlay over image

A Main component

- where all this would be binded
- state would be managed.
- Button with loading more items on Any OnClick fetch triggered.
- Map Different Carousels here

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a pure front end design question as it won't affect backend, or put it this way, they are interrelated but not interdependent.

Foe frontend, the natural way is each tile will be a component and each row will be the component that contain x number of tiles, 3 in your case but you can always pass as props to change the number of tiles per row. And your main component/container of the page will again contain y number of rows, 3 in your case and as mentioned you can pass as props to change the number of row you show.

Indeed, everything will be depends on your data, your payload from the API (assume), dictate how many hows and how many tile per rows. And you also need to determine you UI want end user to update the tile one by one or many tiles in one go. they are related but each design won't affect each other in the sense that how you structure your React component.

Hope this help